# What does the phrase пойти в разведку mean?

Tags: лексикон, выражения, значения

I assume that in casual usage, it doesn't really mean to serve in an intelligence agency, or to reconnoiter an enemy position, right?

Comment: Go to spying, to insearch information

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This expression historically stems from the time of WWII (one should take into account the severe militarisation of the Soviet society and that both the TV and cinema were full of heroic films about WWII). In casual usage it just means that you trust a person.

Answer (score 29):

> Я пошел бы с ним в разведку → I would trust him with my life.

The original, literal meaning is indeed ***to reconnoiter an enemy position*** (and not *to serve in an intelligence agency*).

Comment: It would be helpful to translate the whole phrase: "I would go on a scouting mission with him."

Answer (score 12):

Давно смолкли залпы орудий
авт.В.Высоцкий

Давно смолкли залпы орудий,
Над нами лишь солнечный свет, -
На чем проверяются люди,
Если войны уже нет?

Приходится слышать нередко
Сейчас, как тогда:
"Ты бы пошел с ним в разведку?
Нет или да?"

Comment: -1. How is this an answer?

Comment: Actually - it is. The phrase has become wildely used partly because of this song, and partly the song answers the question.

Comment: *The phrase has become wildely used partly because of this song* If one does some research he finds that the phrase has been already established in the popular culture before 1968... E.g. «Солдат Иван Бровкин» (1955): *С вами, Бровкин, никто даже в разведку-то не пойдет!*